# executing large mysql procedure . error code 2013, when repeated it gives error code 1205

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have written the following procedure to run on a database having 700 000 entries.
I was having a timeout error so I extended the timeout to be 6000 rather than 600. This did not solve it. I get a lost connection error, then I repeat the call it gives a lock wait timeout error.

Is there a more efficient way to do the same task?

The code is joining two tables getting a count of an occurrence of an event an finally displaying the percentage this count was greater then zero.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `EvaluateOutput4`()

BEGIN

declare v_max int default (Select  count(*) FROM tracker.results);
declare v_counter int default 0;
start transaction;

while v_counter < v_max do


 SET @v1 :=
(Select  count(*)
 FROM tracker.Meetings LEFT outer JOIN  tracker.Visits  on tracker.Meetings.visit1 =tracker.Visits.id or tracker.Meetings.visit2 =tracker.Visits.id 
where (tracker.Meetings.user1= (Select VehicleID from tracker.results where RecordID= v_counter) or tracker.Meetings.user2=(Select VehicleID from tracker.results where RecordID= v_counter) ) 
and tracker.Visits.node=(Select Node from tracker.results where RecordID= v_counter)  
and HOUR(time)>=(Select ArrivalTime from tracker.results where RecordID= v_counter) -1 
and HOUR(time)<=(Select ArrivalTime from tracker.results where RecordID= v_counter)+1) ;


Update results  set results.Count=  @v1
Where results.RecordID=v_counter;

set v_counter = v_counter + 1;

end while;

SET @v2 := (Select count(*)from results where results.Count !=0 );
Set @v4 :=(@v2*100/v_max); 
select @v4;

 commit;

END
```